# How do I use ADODB connection in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, ado, adodb

How do I use ADODB for an open file?

1. I need data by array
2. Target file is on the network and data value added in a 10 sec
3. Need to connect to this .xls file and make a real time chart

I tried:

1st:

```
dim path as string, DB as string
dim cnt as ADODB.Connection
OLEDB = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & path & DB & "; 
extended properties=""excel 12.0 xmlHDR=YES"";"
Set cnt = New ADODB.Connection
cnt.Open OLEDB
```

I got an error

> can't find ISAM installation

2nd:

```
dim path as string, DB as string
dim cnt as ADODB.Connection
OLEDB = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & path & DB &"; 
extended properties=""excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;';"""
Set cnt = New ADODB.Connection
cnt.Open OLEDB
```

I got

> 3706 runtime error, can't find supporter

Answer (score 0):

This is how I usually get it running:

```
DbConn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
            "Data Source=" & path & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0; HDR=YES"";"
```

Where path is the full file path + file name.
You can find more Informations on Connection strings [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/)

Worksheet name and Range then go in the SQL Statement. For example:

```
sqlWhere = sheetName & "$A1:$Z1000"
DbRecSet.Open "SELECT * FROM [" & sqlWhere & "]", DbConn, adOpenStatic
```

### Edit:

If i understand you correctly,
you have a single cell that changes value every 10 seconds and you want to get that value via ADODB.

First of all, in this case, you can scrap `HDR=YES` from the connection string.

let's say that cell is `A1`

```
sqlWhere = sheetName & "$A1"
DbRecSet.Open "SELECT * FROM [" & sqlWhere & "]", DbConn, adOpenStatic
returnValue = DbRecSet.Fields(0)
```

Comment: That is one of the great answare I had

Comment: First of all Thank you very much
And now at this moment 
How can I determine that file range which inside a Path specific column and row value?
Actually That row value is changing in a 10 second
so is there any solution?

Comment: As i said, you set the Range you want to query in the SQL Statement. If you want to loop your code every 10 seconds, you could make use of `Application.OnTime`.

Comment: thanks for help. but i didnt understand exactly. if i wanna need specific column data from specific key word which already inside target file located in network. then is it possible to figure it out that column info. to get a data?? best regard

Comment: I edited my answer. If it helped you, feel free to accept the answer.
How you make it loop is a completely different thing and not part of your original question.

Comment: Data Base is not normal form (5 rows are title even some cells are combined), so have to need use range address for making another database which is located another folder ... so is it possible to make a another database not using a title for using a ADODB, actuaclly i didnt understand  your answer code sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

path = test_fdr & "" & today_total & ".xls"

```
 OLEDB = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= " & path & 
 ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES"";"

  Set cnt = New ADODB.Connection
  cnt.Open OLEDB

  Rcdset.Open Source:="[" & TestSheetName & "$]", _
  ActiveConnection:=cnt, _
  CursorType:=adOpenStatic, _
  LockType:=adLockReadOnly, _
  Options:=adCmdTable

  With Sheets(3).QueryTables.Add(Connection:=Rcdset, Destination:=Target_rng)
```

Comment: why that code give me so many missing data ?? i just try to paste whole data using that code but got a problem